# Mapping DataTable to a concrete type

Tags: c#, generics, .net-datatable

I have an extension that adds values to a class and I was wondering if there was a faster way to do this.

Does a for loop execute faster or would a LINQ query do better?

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable dt) where T : class, new()
{
    List<T> dataTableList = new List<T>();
    var rowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    var columnCount = dt.Columns.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        T obj = new T();
        int j = -1;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (j == -1)
            {
                property.SetValue(obj, Guid.NewGuid());
            }
            else if (j < columnCount)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i][j] == null) continue;
                property.SetValue(obj, dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
            }
            j++;
        }
        dataTableList.Add(obj);
    }
    return dataTableList;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this to be faster? Is this slow? How did you measure it?

Comment: @t3chb0t, I have not measured the speed, but I was wondering if there was a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use Dapper -- https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper -- instead of writing ADO.NET code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't say, your major concern should be performance. I find the method rather error prone and it has a very limited use:

1) All columns have to be of type `string` - except the first which must be of type `Guid`

2) The order of the columns in the table must match the order of the properties of the object type. If they don't, a column could easily be mapped with a wrong property without no warning because they must all be strings. You definitely need some type checking.

3) A data table usually has a (unique) Id column, which the instances of the class should be instantiated with, but it seems, that you create a new object Id for every new instance/row. Is that Id saved to the database? And what about the next time the `Row/Item` are mapped - is a new Id again created for that item? It seems not logical to have a new id for an item every time it is fetched from a database?

I would say that the method is so aimed at a special situation where you need to map a data table with a certain `class` that it is not a candidate as an extension method - but just as a private method in a class. An extension method should be generic as much as possible and should handle all possible errors in a consistent way.

What about `private vs. public` members?

---

I personally don't like the use of an indexed iteration here: I would go along these lines:

```
  PropertyInfo[] pis = typeof(T).GetProperties();

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    T item = new T();

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
      PropertyInfo pi = pis.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == column.ColumnName);
      if (pi != null)
      {
        pi.SetValue(item, row[column]);
      }
    }
  }
```

or

```
  PropertyInfo[] pis = typeof(T).GetProperties();

  foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  {
    T item = new T();

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pis)        
    {
        pi.SetValue(item, row[dt.Columns[pi.Name]]);
    }
  }
```

Notice, that the call to `typeof(T).GetProperties()` is outside the loops, because there is no need to call it for every `row/item`. In this way you are half the way to a nearly completely generic extension method.

---

In order to make it more generic, you'll have to consider the mapping strategy:

1) Should the column names match the property names of the class or should you consider to be able to provide a mapping table?:

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable dt, Dictionary<string, string> mappings) where T : class, new()
```

or:

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable dt, (string column, string property)[] mappings) where T : class, new()
```

You'll also have have to consider conversion of certain types: for instance is `DateTime` often stored in a data table as `SqlDateTime` which can not implicitly cast to a `DateTime` structure, so you should maybe be able to provide some converters:

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable dt, (string column, string property)[] mappings, Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>> converters) where T : class, new()
```

called like:

```
    Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>> converters = new Dictionary<string, Func<object, object>>
    {
      { "BirthDay", (sqlDate) => ((SqlDateTime)sqlDate).Value }
    };


    List<MyItem> items = table.DataTableToList<MyItem>(null, converters);
```

Both the mapping and converter strategy can probably be more elegant or sophisticated - the above is merely some quick suggestions.

Comment: +1, but that `FirstOrDefault` call in the innermost loop is repeatedly doing the same work. Better to create an array of valid `(column, propertyInfo)` tuples up-front and use that in the inner loop.